# Querying in the middle of a word with algolia autocomplete

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, algolia

I'm using ALgolia autocomplete with Vuejs and it works fine.

However, when I search for a letter, for example, the letter 'u' which is present in Makuyu and Muingi words it doesn't suggest the words.

How can I achieve this? Any assistance is highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<template>
  <div class="app-container">
    <h1>Vue Application</h1>
    <div id="autocomplete" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="jsx">
import { h, Fragment, render, onMounted } from "vue";
import algoliasearch from "algoliasearch/lite";
import { autocomplete, getAlgoliaResults } from "@algolia/autocomplete-js";
import "@algolia/autocomplete-theme-classic";

export default {
  name: "AutoComplete",
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => {
      autocomplete({
        container: "#autocomplete",
        getSources({ query, setQuery, refresh }) {
          return [
            {
              sourceId: "properties",
              getItems({query}) {
                return getAlgoliaResults({
                  searchClient: algoliasearch(
                    "5ALV3LSLJ1",
                    "bde35d15e4037209a089a5731721c6c1"
                  ),
                  queries: [
                    {
                      indexName: "properties",
                      query,
                      params: {
                        hitsPerPage: 5,
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                });
              },
      templates: {
                item({ item, components }) {
                  return (
                    <div className="aa-ItemWrapper">
                      <div className="aa-ItemContent">
                        <div className="aa-ItemContentBody">
                          <div className="aa-ItemContentTitle">
                            <components.Highlight hit={item} attribute="location" />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
                },
              },
          
            },
          ];
        },
        renderer: { createElement: h, Fragment, render },
      });
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: not possible by design https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/optimize-search-results/override-search-engine-defaults/how-to/how-can-i-make-queries-within-the-middle-of-a-word/

Comment: workaround is when indexing create a field which contains substrings ['akuyu','kuyu','uyu','yu','u'] and set it as searchable attribute

Comment: @cmgchess Could you please explain more about how to implement that? What would the code look like? Thanks

Comment: where do you index your documents? is it server side? btw even then the u will not be highlighted since the hit is coming from the array, not the location field

Comment: @cmgchess Sorry for the late reply. If by indexing you mean where the array with the data that gets suggested is stored then it's stored in Algolia.

Comment: yeah yeah, what i meant was how do you send your data to algolia. do you do in a backend or do you use some script or manually in algolai dashboard?

Comment: I used the backend by leveraging the Algolia Scout package which sends the data to Algolia(https://www.algolia.com/doc/framework-integration/laravel/getting-started/installation/?client=php).

Comment: ahh im sorry i havent used algolia scout but [this](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/optimize-search-results/override-search-engine-defaults/how-to/how-can-i-make-queries-within-the-middle-of-a-word/) has an example codesnippet how you can create an array of prefixes and save in index in php

Comment: Thanks, had seen this in the documentation but I don't understand the docs on this so implementing it in using Vue has been a challenge to me.

Comment: when sending data to algolia. can you send custom field? do you know how to update the existing data in algolia by adding a new field. if so add a prefix field containing substrings like ['akuyu','kuyu','uyu','yu','u']. should be possible with [this](https://www.algolia.com/doc/framework-integration/laravel/advanced-use-cases/access-api-directly/?client=php)

Comment: Yes, currently I'm doing this in my model  to save location in Algolia
```public function toSearchableArray()
  {
    return [
      'location' => $this->location,
    ];
  }```

I guess I can add a custom field in the array and it should work.

Comment: Will it look like this `['prefix' =>  ['akuyu','kuyu','uyu','yu','u']]` ?

Comment: Yes should look like that. After adding to index you have to make it a searchable attribute

Comment: @cmgchess, it did not work. This is how I added the prefix in my already working code.
 ```public function toSearchableArray()
  {
    return [ 'location' => $this->location, 'prefix' =>  ['akuyu', 'kuyu', 'uyu', 'yu', 'u']];
  }```